# W2 Copy A different then Copy B & 2 & C?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, form-w-2

I received my W2 form in the mail from my employer. There is a Red form that apparently is called 'Copy A'. Then there is the standard black and white form with Copy B, Copy 2, and Copy C on it.

The amount of income on Copy A does not agree with the other 3. It is a bit higher. What do I do with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren’t supposed to get Copy A. Copy A is for the IRS. Normally, you never see Copy A. However, all the copies are supposed to agree, and the fact that you received Copy A that doesn’t match your other copies is worrisome.  You should talk to your employer. Ask them why the amounts are different on the different copies, ask them which total is correct, and ask them what they actually reported to the IRS. This will indicate whether or not they need to update your W-2.

When you file your taxes, use Copy B (assuming it is correct).  Copy B is to be used for your federal form, and if you are mailing in a paper tax return, you attach Copy B to your return.